# Initializing array with letters automatically in R, possible?

Tags: r

I know I can use Numbers <- c(1:26) to initializing 1 to 26 to Numbers, but is there any similar way to initializing array Alphabet with letters like that?
Alphabet <- c("a":"z") not work!

Comment: Yes. there are a few built-in constants within R: see `?letters` -- for example `letters[1:26]` or `LETTERS[1:26]`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns oh well thank you